# Illustrator: how to add segment to a closed path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, illustration, pen-tool, anchor-point

I created a rectangle by pointing and clicking 4 anchor points. My question is, is there a way to connect two already existing anchor points to create a diagonal segment? I am trying hard with the pen tool and the direct selection tool but I'm not having any luck. Thanks!

Comment: Lucian's answer is correct.. but to expand a bit.. In Illustrator anchor points can *only* have 2 path segments connected to them - an "in" and an "out". It's never possible to have an anchor point with 3 paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the path is closed you need to open it by removing one segment between 2 corners (left image). Then add 2 points away from the corners (middle image). Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> and drag these 2 points on top of your corners (right image).

[image]
Be advised this will leave the path *open* since you cannot use the same anchor point twice for a closed path. It will *look* closed, but it will be *open*.

So if you need different colours for each half of the shape, this will not work. You will have to build 2 different triangular & closed paths.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Lucian, very clear!! Playing around I also found an alternate solution that is using a segment between the anchor points. But sad that is not possible to connect anchor points multiple times, as in geometric design would be really useful

Comment: You probably need to use multiple closed shapes instead of _simulating_ with an open shape. If you feel this answers your question try clicking the _check_ icon and the _up_ arrow next to my answer above. Thanks!

Comment: When you see something like this, these are all separate closed shapes to be able to use color individually - https://wlester.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/pattern5.jpg

Comment: Thank you, i will check this technique out as I'll probably want to use this type of color filling that remind of shadows in my works. Thanks a lot!